# Generics class and other program syntax issue is generating errors within foreach loop

Tags: c#, generics, foreach

On 'tree' in the foreach loop, I am getting the error: foreach statement cannot operate on type Tree because Tree does not contain a public instance definition for GetEnumerator.

On the second 'data' in foreach loop I am getting error, cannot convert from 'T' to string.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PSearchTreeJW
{
    public class Program 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string[] stringArray = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };

            var stringTree = new Tree<string>();

            PopulateTree(stringArray, stringTree, nameof(stringTree));
            TraverseTree(stringTree, nameof(stringTree));



            Console.WriteLine($"\n \nTree Size: ");
            Console.WriteLine($"{stringTree.Size}");

            //Console.WriteLine("Find C");
            // var node = tree.Find("C");

        }

        public static void PopulateTree<T>(Array array, Tree<string> tree, string name) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\n\nInserting into :");

            foreach (T data in tree)
            {
                Console.Write($"{data}");
                tree.InsertNode(data);
            }
        }
        public static void TraverseTree<T>(Tree<string> tree, string treeType) where T : IComparable
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\nPreorder traversal");
            tree.PreorderTraversal();

            Console.WriteLine($"\n\nInorder traversal");
            tree.InorderTraversal();

            Console.WriteLine($"\n\nPostorder traversal");
            tree.PostOrderTraversal();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Tree`?

Comment: Looks like you'll have to change your signature to `public static void PopulateTree<T>(Array array, Tree<T> tree, string name)`

Comment: Why is your method generic, when the provided `Tree`-parameter is of type `Tree<string>`? Either you have a tree of strings and then your method surely is not generic at all, or it should accept a `Tree<T>` instead of `Tree<string>`.

Comment: At first, I tried creating a new object Tree<T> stringTree = new Tree<T>(); but kept getting errors about 'T'